# Jquery slider to change interval on refresh script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i'm using this piece of code to refresh my div every X seconds:

```
     <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").load("stats.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#container").load('stats.php');
   }, 10*1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

This works great, only thing i want to add is a slider like this one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps

I want it to be able to set the interval on the refresh timer which is by default 10 seconds (10*1000)

Is it possible to let the slider modify the value ? if so, how can i do that ?

thanks!

Comment: Do you have read jQuery UI slider's methods? http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#widget-docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script will be something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var intSeconds = 10;
     var refreshId;


     function sTimeout()
     {
          // Load content
          $("#container").load("stats.php");

          // Saving the timeout
          refreshId = setTimeout(function() {
             sTimout();
         }, intSeconds *1000);
     }
     sTimeout();
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

     // The slider
     $(".ui-slider").slider({
         min : 1, // minimum value
         max : 20, // Maximum value
         value : intSeconds, // Copy current  value
         change: function(event, ui) {
             clearTimeout(refreshId); // clear it
             intSeconds = ui.value; // Update value
             sTimeout();  // Restart it
         }
     });
});
```

Now just add a slider DIV to your source, and check it out.

Comment: Better example than mine, nice!

Comment: Perhaps using 0 as min-value isn't the best idea, as it will cause setTimeout to trigger with extreme frequency, causing a very large amount of requests against stats.php. Or am I wrong about the behavior of setTimeout?

Comment: No you are right, it should be set to 1, other wise the setTimeout will be called every 0 ms

Comment: I've added a slider div, the slider itself is working, the refresh isn't anymore, any idea ?  I was also wondering what's the difference between # and . for example here:  // The slider
     $(".ui-slider").slider   i noticed the slider itself only shows up if use # instead of .  ?

Comment: I've made a typo function sTimout() had to be function sTimeout(), I've missed de "e" after the tim*out()

Answer (score 0):

Add the slider something like this:

```
var interval = 10000;
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:10,
  min: 1,
  max: 20,
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    interval = ui.value * 1000;
  }
});
```

Then instead of using a setInterval, you could use setTimeout:

```
(function reload () {
      $("#container").load('stats.php');
      setTimeout(reload(), interval);
   })();
```